# Url_launcher: ld: framework not found Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods, url-launcher

I tried every solution like upgraded flutter, restart system, delete derived data, uninstall and reinstall pods, remove other flags in target but same error.
here is all log

```
 Ld /Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/url_launcher_ios.framework/url_launcher_ios normal (in target 'url_launcher_ios' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/milesnanton/Desktop/app/float/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk -<br/>L/Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios -F/Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios -F/Users/milesnanton/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7 -filelist <br/>/Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/url_launcher_ios.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/url_launcher_ios.framework/url_launcher_ios -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/url_launcher_ios_lto.o -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/url_launcher_ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/url_launcher_ios_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/milesnanton/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dwoeqpqugkcdzlebfctpnzmnfsee/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/url_launcher_ios.framework/url_launcher_ios
```

[image: error image]

Comment: did you use M1 ?

Comment: It seems like the error itself is missing. Is there more that was logged that you could provide?

Comment: I added details. Please Can you help!